# How can I change to post method in Linking.openURL?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native

i'm using react-native

I want to log out through Linking.openURL.

The open url address uses a service called kakao.

The homepage explains like this

```
URL
POST /v1/user/logout HTTP/1.1
Host: kapi.kakao.com
Authorization: Bearer {ACCESS_TOKEN}

example

       curl -v -X POST "https://kapi.kakao.com/v1/user/logout" \
      -H "Authorization: Bearer {ACCESS_TOKEN}"


      Response
    HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
    {
        "id":123456789
    }
```

So I wrote my code like this, but when I run my code, but it is suppose to get

"id":123456789 but there is nothing And the login status persists

[image]

this is my code

```
    const Myinfo = ({navigation}) => {
      const logoutfunction = async () => {
        const ACCESS_TOKEN = await AsyncStorage.getItem('accesstoken');
        console.log('ACCESS_TOKEN:::', ACCESS_TOKEN);

            fetch('http://kapi.kakao.com/v1/user/logout', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        Authorization: `Bearer ${ACCESS_TOKEN}`,
      },
    }).then((response) => console.log(response));

      return (
        <Logout activeOpacity={0.8} onPress={() => logoutfunction}>
          <LogoutText>logout</LogoutText>
        </Logout>
      );
    };
```

so how can i fix my code?

Comment: You need a background POST request to the server, however you're trying to open the link in a suitable app. Use [`fetch()`](https://reactnative.dev/docs/network) instead.

Comment: @ChrisG can you show me a code? how can i fix my code?

Comment: Did you look at the page I linked in my comment? It has a POST example right at the top, including headers.

Comment: @ChrisG yse i did like this

const logoutfunction = async () => {
    const ACCESS_TOKEN = await AsyncStorage.getItem('accesstoken');
    console.log('ACCESS_TOKEN:::', ACCESS_TOKEN);

    fetch('http://kapi.kakao.com/v1/user/logout', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        Authorization: `Bearer ${ACCESS_TOKEN}`,
      },
    }).then((response) => console.log(response));

but it didn't work

Comment: Put the code you've tried in your question, and explain exactly how it didn't work, what you've done to debug it, etc. Provide as much info as possible.

Comment: @ChrisG i edited my question can you check please?

Comment: The Content-Length of the response suggests that it *is* giving you the data you expect. You haven’t written any code to decode the body and look at it (as any introductory guide to fetch will tell you to do). I’ve no idea what you mean by ‘the login status persists’: What login status? Stored where? How can you tell?

Comment: @Quentin
I mean, if that code works successfully, the logged out ID appears as a response value. Also, login persist means that the user status should be logged out after logout, but the user is still logged in.

Comment: You need `.then(r => r.json()).then(response => console.log(response));` to see the actual response. Also, unless there is some socket.io stuff elsewhere, you need to change the app state yourself; logging out of the API will only affect future requests  but not automatically switch your UI to "logged out"

Comment: @ChrisG i updated my question, but i wonder as you see there is url: "https://kapi.kakao.com/404.json"
what is this mean? Does this mean that an error occurred in the response?